# Counterexample Maschke's theorem

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory

I need to show a counterexample to Maschke's theorem in the case $carK | |G|$.
My professor showed this example which I don't understand.
Let $V=V(n,q)$ be a vector space with $q=p^a$, $K=GF(q)$ (a Galois field of order q), $|GL(n,q)|=(q^n-1)$, $carK=p$. I take $G=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & \dots & * \\ \dots & 1 & \dots \\ 0 & \dots & 1\end{matrix}\right]$ a p-Sylow subgroup. Then I notice that $|G|=q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$. I consider the vector G-invariant $\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \dots \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right]$. How can I now complete the proof? How can I prove that this vector doesn't have a complement? Thank you!

Comment: Take some vector and act on it by suitable elements from the group until you get an element in your invariant subspace.

Comment: I still don't understand :( I need to prove that there is not a complement! How could your suggestion help me?

Comment: A complement will contain some non-zero vector. If you follow my hint you have therefore shown that there cannot be a complement, as any non-zero subrepresentation will intersect non-trivially with the given one.